# Is there a keyboard shortcut for formatting sources in Chrome's Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Dev Tools has a button to format sources: **{ }**

Is there a keyboard shortcut associated with this feature and/or can one be defined?

Comment: There's none. See also https://crbug.com/174309. You can manually build chromium or just its resources.pak with devtools code and add a hotkey, though...

Answer (score 1):

There is not, from what I can tell, a way to do this at this time.

I have created [749068 - Keyboard shortcut - chromium - Monorail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=749068) for anyone interested in such a feature.